# why textfromfield not updating it value on flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Trying to generate a dynamic list of TextFormFields. When I try to add new TextFormFields on onTap of another widget it works fine. After then when I added 2 TextFormFields which is added perfectly and I am successful to set and get values from both fields, but whenever I try to delete the 1st TextFormField the value remains the same I don't know why the UI of TextFormFields not updating? Because when I debug my code all the values are updating but not the UI and when I move to the previous page of my application and come back to the list of TextFormFields page then the UI of TextFormFields will update. I am using **ListBody** widget.

```
static List<String> partnerNameFieldsList = [];
```

Code to add or remove the TextFormField:

```
List<Widget> _getPartnersDetailsFields() {
    List<Widget> partnerDetailFields = [];
    for(int i = 0; i < partnerNameFieldsList.length; i++) {
      partnerDetailFields.add(
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          children: [
            PartnerDetailsFields(i),
            _removeButton(i),
          ],
        )
      );
    }
    return partnerDetailFields;
  }
```

Remove TextFormField functionality:

```
Widget _removeButton(int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15.0, bottom: 0.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          print(index);
          // _partners.removeAt(index);
          partnerNameFieldsList.removeAt(index);
          partnerCnicFieldsList.removeAt(index);
          setState((){ });
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.delete,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I create a different class that is extended by the statefulwidget:

```
class PartnerDetailsFields extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  PartnerDetailsFields(this.index);
  @override
  _PartnerDetailsFieldsState createState() => _PartnerDetailsFieldsState();
}

class _PartnerDetailsFieldsState extends State<PartnerDetailsFields> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        // Partner/Director Name
        Padding(
          padding: PaddingDetails.FIELD_TOP,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: Utils.showPartnerDirectorNameText(widget.index),
            ),
            validator: (val) {
              if (val.isEmpty) return "Please enter partner name";
              else return null;
            },
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            onChanged: (value) => _AdditionalBusinessDetailsState.partnerNameFieldsList[widget.index] = value,
            initialValue: _AdditionalBusinessDetailsState.partnerNameFieldsList[widget.index],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due how Flutter handles elements in the UI. You need to add a [key](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) to your widget that you remove, so the UI will update properly.